# Show that $\chi(G)=\omega(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, coloring

> Let $(X,<)$ be a poset and $G$ a graph with vertex set $X$. Let $E(G)=\{\{u,v\}: u,v \in X\  \text{and}\ u<v\}$. Show that $\chi(G)=\omega(G)$.

$\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$.

$\omega(G)$ is the number of the vertices in the maximum clique size in $G$.

I don't understand how it is possible to build a partially ordered set with ''$<$'' symbol.

and what does the edge set look like? For me it is always a complete graph.

Comment: The order need not be complete. Consider the poset $( \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6\}, <)$ where $a <b$ if $a|b$. For this poset, your graph would be an union of the complete graphs $\{1,2,6 \}, \{1,3,6\}, \{1,2,4\}$ and $\{1,5\}$.

Comment: @N.S. So $<$ is just a symbol need not to be the usual greater sign

Comment: Yes. As a hint, since any order is transitive, your graph is an union of cliques.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are unfamiliar with the concept of partially ordered sets. Luckily there is a lot of information about them readily available on the internet; see for instance [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Here is a brief overview. A relation $\leq$ on a set $X$ is called a *partial order* if it satisfies the following three criteria:

1. For all $x\in X$ we have $x \leq x$ (reflexivity);
2. If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x = y$ (antisymmetry);
3. If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$, then $x \leq z$ (transitivity).

Given a partial order $\leq$ we define its corresponding strict partial order $<$ by declaring that $a < b$ iff $a \leq b \wedge a \neq b$. (Conversely, given a [strict partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders) $\prec$ we may define the corresponding non-strict partial order $\preceq$ by declaring that $x \preceq y$ iff $x \prec y \vee x = y$.)

This is all very abstract; it helps to see some examples.

- The usual order $\leq$ on the real numbers is a partial order. By restriction, this also orders any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ we may want to consider (in particular $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$).
- A different partial order on $\mathbb{N}^+$ is provided by the *divisibility relation*: we define $n \preceq m$ to mean $m$ is divisible by $n$. It is readily verified that this meets the criteria from the definition. However, now the associated comparability graph is no longer complete: we have $2 \not\preceq 3$ as well as $3 \not\preceq 2$, so there is no edge between $2$ and $3$. We say that $2$ and $3$ are *incomparable*.
- A very natural one: for any set $X$, the power set $\mathcal P(X)$ is ordered by inclusion (denoted $\subseteq$). Again, there are many pairs of incomparable elements in this case (provided $|X| \geq 2$). For instance, if $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint subsets of $X$, then we have $A \not\subseteq B$ and $B \not \subseteq A$. (But $A$ and $B$ need not be disjoint to be incomparable.)
- We may equip any set $X$ with the trivial order: $x \leq y$ if and only if $x = y$. Now the comparability graph has no edges at all.
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) provides a few other examples of partial orders.

In your exercise, you are given a partial order on a (finite) set, but you don't know which one it is. It might be [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), it might be trivial, but it's probably something in between. Nevertheless, this turns out to be enough to prove that the chromatic number and the clique number coincide.

Good luck!

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps you didn't emphasize enough that finiteness is needed. The partially ordered set does not have to be finite, it's enough that the clique number is finite.

Comment: @bof Good point, especially since most of my examples are infinite. Nevertheless, I took it that OP meant "graph" to be "finite graph", judging by the type of course that typically includes these kinds of questions. But yes, it should be noted that the result does not always hold in infinite posets.